terraform to attach multiple disk to multiple instance
I need to provision mutliple instance with multiple disk with using below code
I can able to create single instance using disks" : ["50"] but need to attach multiple disks disks" : ["50","100"] which is not happening.
below is variable which is used to create instance  and attach disk:
configuration = [
  {
    "display_name": "test3"
    "Owner_name" : "rajini.l@oracle.com",
    "no_of_instances" : "2",
    "disks" : ["50"]
  },
  {
    "display_name": "test2"
    "Owner_name" : "rajini.2@oracle.com",
    "no_of_instances" : "1",
    "disks" : ["50"]
  },
  {
    "display_name": "test1"
    "Owner_name" : "rajini.3@oracle.com",
    "no_of_instances" : "1",
    "disks" : ["50"]
  },

]

config:

locals {
  serverconfig = [
    for srv in var.configuration : [
      for i in range(1, srv.no_of_instances+1) : {
        instance_name = "${srv.display_name}-${i}"
        Owner_name = srv.Owner_name
        disks  = srv.disks
      }
    ]
  ]
}

locals {
     disks=[for i in var.configuration : i.disks]
}
locals {
  instances = flatten(local.serverconfig)
}

resource "oci_core_instance" "test_instance" {
    for_each = {for server in local.instances: server.instance_name =>  server}
    availability_domain = "${var.ad}"
    compartment_id = data.oci_identity_compartments.test_compartments.compartments[0].id
    shape = "${var.shape}"
    source_details {
        source_id = data.oci_core_images.test_images.images[0].id
        source_type = "image"
    }
    freeform_tags= {"Owner"= "${each.value.Owner_name}"}
    # subnet_id need to move to variable
    create_vnic_details {
        subnet_id        = "${var.subnet_ociid}"
        assign_public_ip = false
    }
    display_name = "${each.value.instance_name}"
    metadata = {
       #user_data = "${base64encode(file("/net/adcnas402.us.oracle.com/export/local/noarch/admin/scripts/database/x86_overlay.sh"))}"
        user_data = base64encode(templatefile("user_data.sh", {user_email=var.user_email}))
        }
    preserve_boot_volume = false
}

Below code is not working
resource "oci_core_volume" "test_volume" {
        for_each = {for server in local.instances: server.instance_name =>  server}
        compartment_id = data.oci_identity_compartments.test_compartments.compartments[0].id
        size_in_gbs = each.value.disks[*]
        availability_domain = "${var.ad}"

}



Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.oci_core_images.test_images: Refreshing state...
data.oci_identity_compartments.test_compartments: Refreshing state...
data.oci_core_vcn.test_vcn: Refreshing state...
data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ads: Refreshing state...
oci_core_instance.test_instance["test2-1"]: Refreshing state... [id=ocid1.instance.oc1.iad.anuwcljsylvfuiicgiiewb2hxaafmy4wz3bkj3ogffp4jkulkiygoiztiszq]
oci_core_instance.test_instance["test3-1"]: Refreshing state... [id=ocid1.instance.oc1.iad.anuwcljsylvfuiicjxhwwwgpaxnp2q47ldn5ud4bqzee5kpc6xwkq252bv7a]
oci_core_instance.test_instance["test1-1"]: Refreshing state... [id=ocid1.instance.oc1.iad.anuwcljsylvfuiic7522qdc5xjl523wek4nshk5c2x7rvk5xazzbjujunj5a]
data.oci_core_subnets.test_subnets: Refreshing state...
oci_core_instance.test_instance["test3-2"]: Refreshing state... [id=ocid1.instance.oc1.iad.anuwcljsylvfuiici7myt2kdyrdqrek3ejtz2phjucbvsrnzluigffrzzsdq]

Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on instance.tf line 59, in resource "oci_core_volume" "test_volume":
  59:         size_in_gbs = each.value.disks[*]

Inappropriate value for attribute "size_in_gbs": string required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on instance.tf line 59, in resource "oci_core_volume" "test_volume":
  59:         size_in_gbs = each.value.disks[*]




Hi @user24224675, welcome to SO :-) What exactly does it mean Below code is not working? Is there any error? What is the expected output? Please provide us more details.

output for the above code is
output error:
data.oci_core_subnets.test_subnets: Refreshing state...
oci_core_instance.test_instance["test3-2"]: Refreshing state... [id=ocid1.instance.oc1.iad.anuwcljsylvfuiici7myt2kdyrdqrek3ejtz2phjucbvsrnzluigffrzzsdq]
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
on instance.tf line 59, in resource "oci_core_volume" "test_volume":
59:         size_in_gbs = each.value.disks[*]
Inappropriate value for attribute "size_in_gbs": string required.

In my eyes this is the perfect example to use a module...
I would create a structure like this:


instance.tf
this is how the instance.tf will look like:
variable "instance" {
  type = object({
    name  = string
    owner = string
    disks = list(string)
  })
}

variable "compartment_id" {}
variable "shape" {}
variable "ad" {}

# Add other vars as needed

resource "oci_core_instance" "test_instance" {
  shape                = var.shape
  freeform_tags        = { "Owner" = var.instance.owner }
  display_name         = var.instance.name
  compartment_id       = var.compartment_id
  availability_domain  = var.ad
  preserve_boot_volume = false
}

resource "oci_core_volume" "test_volume" {
  for_each            = toset(var.instance.disks)
  compartment_id      = var.compartment_id
  size_in_gbs         = each.value
  availability_domain = var.ad
}

# Add any other resources related to the instance here


main.tf
In the main.tf we will do the transfomation of the input and call the module:
variable "configuration" {
  default = [
    {
      "display_name" : "test3"
      "Owner_name" : "rajini.l@oracle.com",
      "no_of_instances" : "2",
      "disks" : ["50"]
    },
    {
      "display_name" : "test2"
      "Owner_name" : "rajini.2@oracle.com",
      "no_of_instances" : "1",
      "disks" : ["50"]
    },
    {
      "display_name" : "test1"
      "Owner_name" : "rajini.3@oracle.com",
      "no_of_instances" : "1",
      "disks" : ["50"]
    },
  ]
}

locals {
  serverconfig = {
    for x in flatten([
      for srv in var.configuration : [
        for i in range(1, srv.no_of_instances + 1) : {
          name  = "${srv.display_name}-${i}"
          owner = srv.Owner_name
          disks = srv.disks
        }
      ]
    ]) : x.instance_name => x
  }
}

module "instance" {
  source         = "./instance"
  for_each       = local.serverconfig
  instance       = each.value
  compartment_id = "..."
  shape          = "..."
  ad             = "..."
}


The error
And the error you got it was clear, right:
Inappropriate value for attribute "size_in_gbs": string required.
you are passing there something that is not a string that is crystal clear, anything you do something like abc[*] is not going to be a string
